# XML deserialize setting a value based on the element tag

Tags: xml, vb.net, serialization

I have doubts that this is possible but I'm curious.  Is it possible to deserialize xml in such a way that the tag name of an element is used to populate a property value?  For example given this xml:

```
<Test>
    <List>
        <Jake Type="Dog" />
        <Mittens Type="Cat" />
    </List>
</Test>
```

Could result in a list like this:

```
Class Animal
    Property Name As String
    Property Type As String
End Class

Name    Type
------- -------
Jake    Dog
Mittens Cat
```

Comment: well, not with the XmlSerializer class, however, you could do it using the XmlDocumentReader

Answer (score 1):

So, not with Xml Serializer, however, you could solve it with the XmlReader (XmlTextReader) in the following way:

```
Class Animal
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Type As String
End Class

Function ReadDocument(filename As String) As List(Of Animal)
    Dim lst As New List(Of Animal)

    Dim doc As XmlReader

    Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        doc = New Xml.XmlTextReader(fs)
        While doc.Read()
            If doc.NodeType <> XmlNodeType.Element Then
                Continue While
            End If
            If Not String.Equals(doc.Name, "List") Then
                Continue While
            End If
            While doc.Read()
                If doc.NodeType = XmlNodeType.EndElement And String.Equals(doc.Name, "List") Then
                    Exit While
                End If
                If doc.NodeType <> XmlNodeType.Element Then
                    Continue While
                End If
                Dim ani As New Animal
                ani.Name = doc.Name
                If doc.MoveToAttribute("Type") Then
                    ani.Type = doc.Value
                    lst.Add(ani)
                End If
            End While
        End While
    End Using

    Return lst
End Function

Sub Main()
    Dim animals As List(Of Animal) = ReadDocument("./Animals.xml")
    Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", "Name", vbTab, "Type")
    For Each ani As Animal In animals
        Console.WriteLine("{0}{1}{2}", ani.Name, vbTab, ani.Type)
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

Comment: If I were to use this, I guess I would just need to write a custom serialization interface.

Comment: Well yeah, it is also adaptable to your needs, it just a lot more complex in it's usage, if you really want/need it more generic, then custom attributes could help you a lot further...